# How to disallow non-alphanumeric characters in ColdFusion using a RegEx

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 9.0.1.

I am trying to test whether a user has provided a non alphanumeric value. If they have, I want to return false.  I'm pretty sure I am close, but I keep getting an error:

```
Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.
```

I've tried multiple ways of making this work, but I can't get it to work.

Specifically, I want to allow only a through z and 0 through 9. No spaces, or special characters.

Can you help me tweak this?

```
    <cfscript>
        LOCAL.Description = trim(left(ARGUMENTS.Description, 15));
        if (len(LOCAL.Description) lte 4) {
            return false;
        } else if (reMatchNoCase("[^A-Za-z0-9_]", LOCAL.Description) neq "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
    </cfscript>
```

W

Comment: The error message you've posted--and the description of your question--do not add up. The error is related to you examining/treating a variable as though it were simple (string, number, etc) but in fact, the variable is a complex type (object, array, struct, etc). However, your question asks something entirely different--what is the regex pattern to match/disallow a non-alphanumeric character in a string (which is wrapped in the [[:alnum:]] POSIX reference). You may need to go back and re-analyze the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reMatchNoCase returns Array which cannot be compared to the string, use ArrayLen() on the result in order to find out if there any matches

There is actually another problem in your code. First line will produce an error if the length of the description is less than 15, which means that the first IF is obsolete since it will always be false.

Comment: It should not error if the length is < 15. It should just return the whole string "as is".

Comment: Thanks for the solution:  else if (arrayLen(reMatchNoCase("[^A-Za-z0-9_]", LOCAL.Description)) eq 0)

Comment: You could shorten it by just doing this: `else if (!arrayLen(reMatchNoCase("[^A-Za-z0-9_]", LOCAL.Description)))`  That should work in CF 8 as well.

Comment: I do remember a while back encountering errors when doing, for example, `left("x",2)` - but maybe this was an old bug from CFMX, because I've definitely done equivalent in recent versions with no problems.

Comment: That does sound vaguely familiar. But it works in mx6, so the issue may be even further back than that.

Answer (score 2):

> reMatchNoCase("[^A-Za-z0-9_]", LOCAL.Description) neq ""

It is because `ReMatchNoCase` returns an array, not a simple string. Either check the array length, or better yet, use `ReFindNoCase` instead. It returns the position of the first match, or 0 if it was not found.

Comment: @Evik - Welcome :) Since you do not seem to be using the resulting array for anything, I think `ReFind` makes more sense from an efficiency POV.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following approach:

```
<cfscript>
    local.description = trim(local.description);
    return reFind("(?i)^[A-Z0-9_]{5,}$", local.description)?true:false;
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Your use of the ternary `?true:false` there is redundant, but otherwise this solution makes more sense than doing distinct length and character matches.

Comment: Oh, and a simpler regex is simply `^\w{5,}$` - no need for the `(?i)` then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but `reFindNoCase` is the optimal solution in 2021. Here's how I would handle the code in the original question:

```
// best practice not to have a local var name identical to an argument var
var myValue = trim( left( arguments.description, 15 ) );

// return false if myValue is less than 4 or has special characters
return(
   !len( myValue ) lte 4 && 
   !reFindNoCase( "[^a-z0-9]", myValue )
);
```